# Keras load_model not working after training

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have used the sample code here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2295

I am unable to load my model after training it in keras. I get the following error:

`ValueError: Optimizer weight shape (3, 3, 512, 512) not compatible with provided weight shape (256, 43)`

I tried using HDFView and deleting the optimiser weights and reloading. But then I get the error:

```
ValueError: ('shapes (10,4224) and (1128,256) not aligned: 4224 (dim 1) != 1128 (dim 0)', (10, 4224), (1128, 256))
Apply node that caused the error: Dot22(Reshape{2}.0, lstm_2_W_i)
Toposort index: 249
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(10, 4224), (1128, 256)]
Inputs strides: [(16896, 4), (1024, 4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)](Dot22.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0)]]
```

I also tried saving the architecture to JSON and saving weights separately and then loading but even that fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to devise a workaround. I was able to load the trained model using the steps below:

1. Create the Sequential model.
   Example:

   `model = Sequential()
   model.add(...)
   model.add(...)
   model.compile(...)
   model.fit(...)`
2. After training save only model weights using model.save_weights()
   Example:
   `model.save_weights(SaveLocation)`
3. To load the model weights, create the model programmatically just as in step 1 but do not use the model.compile function.
   Example:

   `model = Sequential()
   model.add(...)
   model.add(...)
   model.load_weights(weightFile)`
4. The weights are now loaded successfully.